# NLog Getting Started Tutorial ILogger not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog

I'm trying out logging for the first time and following the tutorial for NLog found at https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-(project.json) however when I get to step 4 where the logs are being written I get a error. The error message that I get is "The type or namespace ILogger<> could't be found". 
This is what I have, as far as I can detect is the exact same thing listed on the tutorial.

```
namespace EmptyAspnetProj.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Index page says hello", new object[0]);

        return View();
    }
```

I must be doing something stupid because I don't see any issues posted to Github with the article. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you already `using NLog.Extensions.Logging;`, as denoted [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-(project.json)#3-update-startupcs)?

Comment: Yes have the following using statements.  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using NLog.Extensions.Logging;
using NLog.Web;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event that anyone else has the same issue it can be resolved by adding.

using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

Comment: I think it's a vs2017 bug. Had something related. Microsoft.Extensions.Logging is a dependency of NLog.Extensions.Logging